# Visual studio FTP publish does not close connections?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ftp, publish

I am publishing using Visual Studio 2010 FTP publish and everything works fine. The problem is that the page I am publishing to does only allow 6 connections from the same IP. As Visual Studio does not close the connection these connections stay open and I exceed the 6 connections quickly and cannot upload.

Does anyone know a solution to this other than using another FTP-program?

Comment: The same issue still exists in VS2012 (RC). This is pretty ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by telling our web hoster to kick me if I am inactive for 1 min. So all connections created by VS will be terminated after 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up the connection using passive mode? 
See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcc56w61.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I solved it and forgot to post an answer